# How to build a specific revision of SVN in Hudson/Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

**Background:**

We use **NAnt** as our building tool.

**Question:**

How can I tell Hudson to build a specific revision in **SVN**, instead of the latest one by default?

Thanks.

Comment: any one try this? http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Release+Manager

Answer (score 43):

You configure the svn location including the revision number

```
<SVN_URL>@revision
```

Instead of putting the revision number hard coded in there you can use a parameter for the hudson job

```
<SVN_URL>@$param
```

Comment: Did u ever try this: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Release+Manager

Comment: Does this feature require a specific SVN version above? I got this error message: '/branches/xxx/website@4518' doesn't exist in the repository. Maybe you meant '/branches/xxx/website'?

Comment: Even so you will get the error message described above when configuring the job, it will checkout the right revision of your code.

Comment: Where do you define `param`?

Comment: That is the name of a build parameter for that job.

Comment: This answer is fine, but the same answer is more understandable written by @Balmipour (below)

Answer (score 9):

*(Lacking rep to comment, so I answer instead)*

Peter answer's works well !

The syntax wasn't very clear to me.  The solution was... reading Jenkins contextual help !
[image: As simple as this !]

The final syntax I used for my repo URL was this one: http://mySVNdomain.com/svn/myREPOname/trunk@414
where 414 was, of course, the revision I needed.

Don't miss the possibility of using @$param if you need something dynamic

Answer (score 7):

Tag the revision, give Hudson the tag url

Comment: Using a tag didn't work for me with Hudson v1.355.  I tried tagging a rev and using xxx/tags/rev instead of xxx/trunk in the "Repository URL" setting.  I also tried the @rrr suffix against the trunk -- this started checking out the trunk as well as ALL the tags and branches (before I killed it).

Answer (score 5):

This is a plugin for Hudson that works really well. It displays a list of revisions and allows you to select one to build.

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Release+Manager