# Building a particular revision in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: svn, msbuild, jenkins, msbuild-task, jenkins-plugins

I am using SVN as my source control repository and Jenkins as my CI tool.  I run MSBuild scripts using Jenkins to do the actual builds and deploys.  I also use the Jenkins Pipeline plugin to do manage the building of downstream projects.

I have an issue with the pipeline.  The problem is that, say I have done 10 check-ins into SVN and as a result 10 automatic CI builds have taken place, and as a result of that the pipeline shows 10 builds.  Now, if I want to push build number 5 to the next stage in the pipeline I would expect all the code up to the fifth build to be built to the next stage, instead what is happening is that the latest code (build 10) is being used all the time.

I don't know whether I need to modify my build script or whether I need to configure Jenkins or whether I need to configure the pipeline plugin.  Does anyone know?

Just in case you don't know what I mean by the pipeline plugin, here is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually configure what you want, or that you really want to.  Here's why:  let's say the first stage takes 1/2 the time to run as the second stage.  If you had a continuous flow of stage 1 builds, that kicked off a build of exactly the same version in stage 2, then you could never complete.  By the time you got 3 stage 1 builds done, you would have only built 1 stage 2. At the point of 9 stage 1 builds, you would be behind by 5 builds. That's why the 2nd stage always builds the latest possible revision.  It solves the catching-up problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add `@1234` to your **SVN_URL** in the SVN location. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2325478/834)

You can also use the environment variable **SVN_REVISION** to get the revision and use something like `@${SVN_REVISION}` in your SVN location. Documentation is available at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables.